# EJB Client freezes on getting the results from a Wildfly 25 or 26

Tags: ejb, wildfly, freeze

I´m currently struggling with EJB remote calls against Wildfly 25 or 26.
Same client application works fine with Widfly 10,13,16,20 and to some extent also with Wildfly 25 or 26.
The problem starts wenn the return object size of the EJB call exceeds some limit, which limit seems to change sometime. Example: I made a test EJB method which returns same string what I provide as parameter. Mostly, if the length of the String exceeds ~65.000 chars, the Wildfly EJB client hangs on reading the result. Anyhow, sometimes I have also experienced that client freezes at more than that limit. In my client I have registered an EJB Call Interceptor and I see that the call freezes when the EJB-context.getResult() is invoked. On server side, also based on a server side interceptor, I see that the call was done, but obviuosly something goes wrong on receiving the return value through the EJB client.
This is the stacktrace of the hanging thread:

```
    "main@1" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA waiting
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
  at org.wildfly.httpclient.common.WildflyClientInputStream.read(WildflyClientInputStream.java:147)
  at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
  at org.jboss.marshalling.SimpleDataInput.read(SimpleDataInput.java:111)
  at org.jboss.marshalling.UTFUtils.readUTFBytes(UTFUtils.java:151)
  at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:314)
  at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:231)
  at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
  at org.wildfly.httpclient.ejb.HttpEJBReceiver$2.getResult(HttpEJBReceiver.java:207)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:620)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
  at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:57)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:622)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.java:148)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:622)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.java:130)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:622)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:87)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:622)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor$$Lambda$94.871790326.get(Unknown Source:-1)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.call(AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.java:59)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.java:52)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:622)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
  at com.ge.hac.ca.common.util.CommonClientInvocationInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(CommonClientInvocationInterceptor.java:196)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:622)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:212)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:622)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:1003)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:182)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:116)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.loopback(Unknown Source:-1)
  at com.ge.hac.ca.perf.connection.TestConnectionToWildfly.checkEJBInvocation_LoggerService(TestConnectionToWildfly.java:225)
  at com.ge.hac.ca.perf.connection.TestConnectionToWildfly.executeEJBIterations(TestConnectionToWildfly.java:191)
  at com.ge.hac.ca.perf.connection.TestConnectionToWildfly.main(TestConnectionToWildfly.java:401)
```

I'm using Amazon Corretto jdk1.8.0_292.

Has anyone experienced similar issue, and if yes, how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

EJB calls with huge result objects (i.e. String >= 64 Kbytes) doesn't work with Wildfly 25 or 26 because I have to use now the HTTP protocol instead of "remoting" what I have used for years before.
Specifically the HTTP/2 implemenattion doesn't work but the HTTP/1 seems to work.

Explanation:
I have checked / debugged the Wildfly client code and in my opinion there are several bugs in both the server and the client code of the HTTP/2 protocol implementation.

First bug: The server sends suddenly (mostly on bigger objects) in the middle of the data stream a FRAME_TYPE_RST_STREAM (see io.undertow.protocols.http2.Http2FrameHeaderParser:191 --> type = header[3] & 0xff;),
which marks the stream as broken (see io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedStreamSourceChannel:684 --> state |= STATE_STREAM_BROKEN;)
and afterwards causes "ClosedChannelExceptions" on all stream reads inside the client (see org.wildfly.httpclient.common.WildflyClientInputStream:58 --> int res = streamSourceChannel.read(pooled.getBuffer());)
I didn't debug the server side code, so I can't tell why the server sends suddenly a "reset stream" on some huge objects. Sometimes the same huge object is transferred to the client without issues. On using HTTP/1 this neever happens so it can't be a network issue.

Second bug (initiated by the above reset stream) : The client can't handle correctly this "ClosedChannelExceptions" initiated by the received reset stream, because it freezes the whole communication.
The client keeps reading from the channel and after each read it invokes the wait(0) on its lock Object (see  org.wildfly.httpclient.common.WildflyClientInputStream:147 --> lock.wait();)
Normally this wait(0) is continued by invoking the notifyAll() of same lock Object (in case of ClosedChannelExceptions it is the org.wildfly.httpclient.common.WildflyClientInputStream:94 --> lock.notifyAll();
Unluckily after the last read and therefore last invoked wait(0), there is no notifyAll() invoked anymore, so the EJB client call freezes for ever. This should not happen under any circumstances in my opinion.

The solution I found is, but I'm not happy with that, to disable the HTTP/2 protocol on the server and use HTTP/1 instead.
standalone-full.xml --> <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" **enable-http2="false"** />

Making now EJB calls through the HTTP/1 protocol works fine for huge Objects as well.

The mentioned classes with line numbers are all taken from Wildlfy 26.0.0 Client jar:

I hope some Wildfly expert will read this and react.